# How to input time in Tkinter and use it to run code?

Tags: python, tkinter, pynput, pysimplegui

I got myself a task to write an auto-run zoom code and make it play some sounds while logging into meeting.

I watched couple tutorials on this, and found one that fit my need. I copy pasted it and just made some tweaks (ALERT: I'm total beginner, like, I started two weeks ago, sorry...). But I noticed all of them used self-typed values for time and link.

What I wanted to do, is to make it interactive, using Tkinter or `PySimpleGUI` (two that I find easier to understand), so that user can input info through GUI and then make that code run at certain time.

What do I need to do to make time-format input widget in GUI? I just wanna make a two brackets, one for time and the other for link to copy paste, that will open at that time.

P.S. This would be the code that I used (this is the link to github where I got it: [ZoomAutoLogin](https://github.com/supersu-man/ZoomAutoLogin), it has imported list which holds all of the values (I have no idea if I can change this code so that it works with GUI.)

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
from data import lst
import webbrowser

keyboard = Controller()

isStarted = False

for i in lst:
    while True:
        if isStarted == False:
            if (datetime.now().hour == int(i[1].split(':')[0]) and
                datetime.now().minute == int(i[1].split(':')[1])):
                webbrowser.open(i[0])
                isStarted = True
        elif isStarted == True:
            if (datetime.now().hour == int(i[2].split(':')[0]) and
                datetime.now().minute == int(i[2].split(':')[1])):
                keyboard.press('w')
                time.sleep(1)
                keyboard.press(Key.enter)
                isStarted = False
                break
```

This would be the list from data:

```
lst = [
    ["link1", "2:00", "2:30"],
    ["link2", "2:31", "3:00"],
    ["link3", "3:01", "3:30"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my one example to select time by mouse wheel in PySimpleGUI.

[image]

```py
from datetime import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup_get_time(start_hour=None, start_minute=None):
    """
    Using mouse wheel to select hour and minute
    :param start_hour: Default value for hour. 0 ~ 23
    :type start_hour: int
    :param start_minute: Default value for hour. 0 ~ 59
    :type start_minute: int
    """
    option = {
        "font": ("Courier New", 48, "bold"),
        "enable_events": True,
        "background_color": None,
        "text_color": "white",
        "justification": "center",
        "pad": (0, 0)
    }
    now = datetime.now()
    hour, minute = now.hour, now.minute
    hour = hour if start_hour is None else max(0, min(int(start_hour), 23))
    minute = minute if start_minute is None else max(0, min(int(start_minute), 59))
    layout = [
        [sg.Text(f"{hour:0>2d}", **option, size=(3, 1), key="Hour"),
         sg.Text(":",  **option),
         sg.Text(f"{minute:0>2d}", **option, size=(3, 1), key="Minute")],
        [sg.Button("OK"), sg.Button("Cancel")],
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Select Time", layout, grab_anywhere=True,
        keep_on_top=True, modal=True, finalize=True)
    hour_element, minute_element = window['Hour'], window['Minute']
    hour_element.bind("<MouseWheel>", "_Wheel")
    minute_element.bind("<MouseWheel>", "_Wheel")

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Cancel"):
            window.close()
            return (None, None)
        elif event == "OK":
            window.close()
            return (hour, minute)
        elif event == "Hour_Wheel":
            delta = -int(hour_element.user_bind_event.delta/120)
            hour = (hour+delta) % 24
            hour_element.update(f'{hour:0>2d}')
        elif event == "Minute_Wheel":
            delta = -int(minute_element.user_bind_event.delta/120)
            minute = (minute+delta) % 60
            minute_element.update(f'{minute:0>2d}')

sg.theme("DarkBlue")

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Date')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Date':
        hour, minute = popup_get_time(5, 20)
        print(f'You set time as {hour:0>2d}:{minute:0>2d}')

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. But how can I use this info to run the other code? Still have no idea how to get these updated values  when I put sg.Input in layout. I want output to go straight into code.